# django CSS files not loading

Tags: python, css, django, caching

I have a Django project in which I am using [django compressor](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/) so when I deployed the site it is requesting minified CSS and javascript files from these types of URLS

/static/CACHE/js/90d8ce19e421.js

static/CACHE/css/1374922f2afa.css, etc.

But when I checked I found out that there is no folder named CACHE inside the static folder. I think these minified files will be automatically created.

How can I force the creation of CACHE folder so that minified files are created
Here are my settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ....,
  compressor
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

Also when I run ./manage.py compress, here is the output

```
Found 'compress' tags in:
/home/ubuntu/websites/simplecode.in/apps/blog/templates/base.html
/home/ubuntu/websites/simplecode.in/apps/blog/templates/post_detail.html
/apps/blog/templates/about.html
/apps/blog/templates/post_list.html
Compressing... done
Compressed 2 block(s) from 4 template(s) for 1 context(s).
```

Comment: try adding an absolute path like `'/var/www/static/'`

Comment: Please note [when `DEBUG=True` then `COMPRESS_ENABLED=False`](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_ENABLED). It is recommended to set `DEBUG=False` when running in production, this would also enable compression.